# How to know the subscription start date and end date of month in stripe json data?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to retrive the subscription object data using nodejs into my project.
Below is the subscription object. So whenever user signs up I want to store their subscription date and subscription next date. What I think is its

```
"current_period_end": 1613973928,
"current_period_start": 1611295528
```

But when I converted the time **1613973928** into Localstring it gives :

```
 "Mon Jan 19 1970 21:49:33 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

This is should be todays date.

```
{
      "id": "sub_Inubyr5OJUppaI",
      "object": "subscription",
      "application_fee_percent": null,
      "billing_cycle_anchor": 1611295528,
      "billing_thresholds": null,
      "cancel_at": null,
      "cancel_at_period_end": false,
      "canceled_at": null,
      "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
      "created": 1611295528,
      "current_period_end": 1613973928,
      "current_period_start": 1611295528,
      "customer": "cus_InubUu9jTKtevF",
      "days_until_due": null,
      "default_payment_method": null,
      "default_source": null,
      "default_tax_rates": [],
      "discount": null,
      "ended_at": null,
      "items": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "si_InubRpC6JA0U6W",
            "object": "subscription_item",
            "billing_thresholds": null,
            "created": 1611295528,
            "metadata": {},
            "price": {
              "id": "price_1Hvs1yGQ1LZjNPNJTN3wuIX0",
              "object": "price",
              "active": true,
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "created": 1607379486,
              "currency": "usd",
              "livemode": false,
              "lookup_key": null,
              "metadata": {},
              "nickname": null,
              "product": "prod_IWvtx3h0tCJQ7c",
              "recurring": {
                "aggregate_usage": null,
                "interval": "month",
                "interval_count": 1,
                "usage_type": "licensed"
              },
              "tiers_mode": null,
              "transform_quantity": null,
              "type": "recurring",
              "unit_amount": 29900,
              "unit_amount_decimal": "29900"
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "subscription": "sub_Inubyr5OJUppaI",
            "tax_rates": []
          }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "url": "/v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_Inubyr5OJUppaI"
      },
      "latest_invoice": "in_1ICIlwGQ1LZjNPNJZGi0UDF0",
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {},
      "next_pending_invoice_item_invoice": null,
      "pause_collection": null,
      "pending_invoice_item_interval": null,
      "pending_setup_intent": null,
      "pending_update": null,
      "schedule": null,
      "start_date": 1611295528,
      "status": "active",
      "transfer_data": null,
      "trial_end": null,
      "trial_start": null
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unix timestamps are in seconds, but JS works in milliseconds:

```
new Date(1613973928 * 1000).toLocaleDateString()
// '2/22/2021'
```

Comment: But still today is: 11th Feb 2021 not // '2/22/2021'

Comment: `1613973928` is `Mon Feb 22 2021 06:05:28 GMT+0000`